# Is it possible to extend the ActiveRecord association definition later?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have a `Quiz`, which has many `Question`s. I want to be able to change the order of those questions inside a quiz. But I don't want to use gems such as `acts_as_list`, because then I would have to store the position column in the `Question` class. And in my opinion, it doesn't belong there; only the `Quiz` should have the knowledge of the order of its questions. So, I want to have a `questions_order` column in `Quiz`, which contains that information.

Because I need to use this pattern in another place, I want to extract that functionality into an extension. So, that extension would look something like this:

```
class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy

  orders :questions
end
```

And that would expand to something like this:

```
class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy,
    after_add: :add_question_order,
    after_remove: :remove_question_order do
      def ordered
        # query for ordering questions
      end
    end
end
```

However, this means that the `orders` method needs to extend the already defined `has_many :questions` association. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: What do you think about have a serialized array like this `serialize :questions_order, Array` to store the order?

Comment: Yes, this is almost exactly what I have. But `questions_order` needs to update itself on adding and removing questions. That's why I also need additional methods, like these callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy,
  after_add: :add_question_order,
  after_remove: :remove_question_order

  serialize :questions_order, Array

  def add_question_order(question)
    update_attribute(:questions_order, questions_order << question.id)
  end

  def remove_question_order(question)
    update_attribute(:questions_order, questions_order.delete(question.id))
  end
end
```

Comment: I edited my question to make it more clear what I was asking for. I have the implementation, I just don't have the ability to further define an association which has already been defined.